# Error: 0xC0209029 at Carga Tabla Hecho, OLE DB Destination [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "OLE DB Destination.In

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I apologize for the previous issues; I hope it is better now. This is the problem I am facing in my ETL project: in the table, when using isnull and setting it to 0, it gives me this issue. Apparently, if I use any other number, for example, 1 (which is an existing example), it runs without a problem with the Check Constraints option activated.

**This is the error that the log provides.**

> Error: 0xC0202009 at Carga Tabla Hecho, OLE DB Destination [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_facventas_dimempleados". The conflict occurred in database "BikeZ_DW", table "dbo.dimempleados", column 'iddimempleado'.".

**The code the query.**

```
SELECT 
    temp.DetalleVentaID, t.iddimtiempo, c.iddimcliente,  
    ISNULL(iddimempleado,0) AS iddimempleado, te.iddimterritorio, 
    p.iddimproducto, temp.Cantidad, temp.PrecioUnitario 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         d.DetalleVentaID, cantidad, precioUnitario, fecha, 
         clienteID, COALESCE(vendedorID,0) AS vendedor_ID, 
         v.territorioID, ProductoID       
     FROM 
         ventas v 
     JOIN 
         DetalleVentas d ON (v.ventaid = d.ventaid)) temp          
JOIN 
    BikeZ_DW.dbo.dimtiempo t ON (temp.fecha = t.fecha)       
JOIN 
    BikeZ_DW.dbo.dimcliente c ON (temp.clienteID = c.idcliente)       
LEFT JOIN 
    BikeZ_DW.dbo.dimempleados e ON (temp.vendedor_ID = e.idempleado)       
JOIN 
    BikeZ_DW.dbo.dimterritorio te ON (temp.territorioID = te.idterritorio)       
JOIN 
    BikeZ_DW.dbo.dimproducto p ON (temp.productoID = P.IDPRODUCTO)
```

**Part of the code for the DW database.**

```
CREATE TABLE dimempleados (
    iddimempleado   INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    idempleado      INT NOT NULL,
    genero          VARCHAR(1) NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (iddimempleado) );

CREATE TABLE facventas (
    idfactventas                    INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    monto                           Money NULL,
    cantidad                        INT NULL,
    dimtiempo_iddimtiempo           INT NOT NULL,
    dimempleados_iddimempleado      INT NOT NULL,
    dimproducto_iddimproducto       INT NOT NULL,
    dimterritorio_iddimterritorio   INT NOT NULL,
    dimcliente_iddimcliente         INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idfactventas,dimempleados_iddimempleado,dimterritorio_iddimterritorio, dimcliente_iddimcliente, dimproducto_iddimproducto, dimtiempo_iddimtiempo)
);

ALTER TABLE facventas
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_facventas_dimempleados
    FOREIGN KEY (dimempleados_iddimempleado)
    REFERENCES dimempleados(iddimempleado)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to improve code and message formatting.

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem: your source data is trying to insert a value for `iddimempleado` that doesn't already exist in the column's related foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [AlwaysLearning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483495/error-0xc0209029-at-carga-tabla-hecho-ole-db-destination-2-ssis-error-code#comment136600499_77483495) observation, your ISNULL check is generating a zero when the employee id is not found. You have a foreign key reference between your fact table (ventas) and dimension (empleados).

The definition of your employee dimension specifies it is an identity that is seeded at one. Therefore, you need to ensure you have an unknown member. Something like

```
-- Add our unknown member if it does not already exist
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.dimempleados ON;
INSERT INTO 
    dbo.dimempleados(iddimempleado, idempleado, genero) 
SELECT X.* 
FROM 
    (
        VALUES(0, 0, 'U') 
    )AS X(iddimempleado, idempleado, genero) 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM dbo.dimempleados AS D 
        WHERE D.idempleados = X.idempleados
    );

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.dimepleados OFF;
```

I would have an Execute SQL Task at the start of my package that ensures the unknown member exists and it will run idempotent statements like the above.